# matplotlib pyplot doesnt plot. Fails with module not found python3-tk

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot using pyplot:
When I try to execute my script. It complains about python3-tk module not found. I understand this package needs to be installed to get this working. Is there any workaround to resolve this?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/frequency.py", line 81, in
>   
>       from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt    File "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 115, in 
>       _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()    File
>   "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py",
>   line 62, in pylab_setup
>       [backend_name], 0)   File "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.   File
>   "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       from six.moves import tkinter as Tk   File "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py",
>   line 92, in **get**
>       result = self._resolve()   File "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py",
>   line 115, in _resolve
>       return _import_module(self.mod)   File "/home/user1/PycharmProjects/programs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py",
>   line 82, in _import_module
>       **import**(name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 38, in 
>       raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package') ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the
>   python3-tk package

Comment: Are you using Python 3, right? Try `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`.

Comment: ok, I will try that. I just wanted to know if there was any workaround for same.

Comment: Really, you wanted to know if there's a workaround to having a module installed before importing it? I'm genuinely curious as to what you'd imagine said workaround to look like.

Comment: No,I am not using module(python3-tk) in my script. I am just saving the figure(which i am plotting) in non-interactive mode, So I thought of asking is there a work around to avoid installing python3-tk module.

Comment: @aradhanasingh Use a non-interactive [backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) like `agg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to this issue.
https://github.com/ufoym/deepo/issues/17

try using this code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

As Dalton suggested it is best to install python3-tk.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3, try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

If the Python version is 3.6:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

Repository needed for `python3.6-tk`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```